# Understanding a monoid ring through example

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, notation, symmetric-groups, monoid

I am trying to understand what a monoid ring is. My lecture script gives me the following definition (my translation from German):

Let $G$ be a monoid. We define the set $$RG := \{f: G \to R \mid f(\sigma) \ne 0 \text{ for finitely many } \sigma \in G\}$$ together with addition $$f+g: G \to R, \sigma \mapsto f(\sigma) + g(\sigma)$$ and multiplication $$f \cdot g: G \to R, \sigma \mapsto \sum_{\tau, \rho \in G \atop t \cdot \rho = \sigma}f(\tau)g(\rho).$$ This must be a ring, which is commutative iff $G$ is abelian. Further the script says that we can use the inclusions $$R \to RG, a \mapsto f_a \text{ with } f_a:G \to R, \sigma \mapsto a \cdot \delta_{\sigma, \iota} = \begin{cases}a & \text{ if } \sigma = \iota, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ and $$G \to RG, \tau \mapsto f_\tau \text{ with } f_\tau:G \to R, \sigma \mapsto \delta_{\sigma, \tau} = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } \sigma = \tau, \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ to interpret $R$ and $G$ as subsets of $RG$. This way we can get the representation $$f = \sum_{\sigma \in G}a_\sigma \cdot \sigma$$ with $a_\sigma = f(\sigma) \in R$.

So what I tried to do is to set $R := \mathbb{Z}, G := S_3 = \{id, (1 2), (1 3), (2 3), (1 2 3), (3 2 1)\}$. I took $f$ as a simple function $$\begin{array}{rcl}id & \mapsto & 0\\ (1 2) & \mapsto & 1 \\ (1 3) & \mapsto & 2 \\ (2 3) & \mapsto & 3 \\ (1 2 3) & \mapsto & 4 \\ (3 2 1) &\mapsto& 5.\end{array}$$

Then, trying to decrypt the 1. inclusion I got $$\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}S_3, a \mapsto f_a \text{ with } f_a:S_3 \to \mathbb{Z}, \sigma \mapsto a \cdot \delta_{\sigma, \iota} = \begin{cases}a & \text{ if } \sigma = \iota \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ This way I got the functions
$$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
f_1: & id & \mapsto & 1 &,&f_2: & id & \mapsto & 2 & f_3: \ldots\\ 
& (1 2) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (1 2) & \mapsto & 0 \\
& (1 3) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (1 3) & \mapsto & 0 \\
& (2 3) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (2 3) & \mapsto & 0 \\
& (1 2 3) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (1 2 3) & \mapsto & 0 \\
& (3 2 1) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (3 2 1) & \mapsto & 0 \\
\end{array}$$
This inclusion maps $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ to a function $f_a \in \mathbb{Z}S_3$ which maps $id$ to $a$ and sends the rest to $0$.

That I decrypted the 2. inclusion and got
$$S_3 \to \mathbb{Z}S_3, \tau \mapsto f_\tau \text{ with } f_\tau:S_3 \to \mathbb{Z}, \sigma \mapsto \delta_{\sigma, \tau} = \begin{cases}1 & \text{ if } \sigma = \tau \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$ together with the functions
$$\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
f_{id}: & id & \mapsto & 1 &,&f_{(1 2)}: & id & \mapsto & 0 & f_{(1 3)}: \ldots\\ 
& (1 2) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (1 2) & \mapsto & 1 \\
& (1 3) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (1 3) & \mapsto & 0 \\
& (2 3) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (2 3) & \mapsto & 0 \\
& (1 2 3) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (1 2 3) & \mapsto & 0 \\
& (3 2 1) & \mapsto & 0 &&& (3 2 1) & \mapsto & 0 \\
\end{array}$$
This inclusion maps every $\tau \in S_3$ to a function $f_\tau$ which maps $\tau$ to $1$ and the rest to $0$.

After that I took my simple function $f:$ $$\begin{array}{rcl}id & \mapsto & 0\\ (1 2) & \mapsto & 1 \\ (1 3) & \mapsto & 2 \\ (2 3) & \mapsto & 3 \\ (1 2 3) & \mapsto & 4 \\ (3 2 1) &\mapsto& 5.\end{array}$$ and tried to decompose it in $$f = \sum_{\sigma \in S_3} a_\sigma \cdot \sigma$$ with $a_\sigma = f(\sigma) \in \mathbb{Z}$, as mentioned before.

This way I got $$\begin{array}{rcl}f &=& a_{id}\cdot id + a_{(1 2)}\cdot (1 2) + a_{(1 3)} \cdot (1 3) + a_{(2 3)}\cdot (2 3) + a_{(1 2 3)}\cdot (1 2 3) + a_{(3 2 1)} \cdot (3 2 1)\end{array} \\ = f(id) \cdot id + f((1 2)) \cdot (1 2) + f((1 3)) \cdot (1 3) + f((2 3)) \cdot (2 3) + f((1 2 3)) \cdot (1 2 3) + f((3 2 1)) \cdot (3 2 1) \\ = (1 2) + 2\cdot (13) + 3 \cdot (2 3) + 4 \cdot (1 2 3) + 5 \cdot (3 2 1).$$

At this point I started to ask myself what the hell is going on here, and after sitting a following hour with that I can not understand what is happening here anymore. Both parser and lexer in my brain do not come clear with that so that looking at $4 \cdot (1 2 3)$ I am asking myself what to do with that. It is also hard for me to imagine how can I evaluate $f$ because e.g. $(4 \cdot (1 2 3))(1 3)$ looks a bit dangerous.

Have I made a mistake somewhere? Should I use the inclusions further to get something that makes sense? Could you please help me to get this certain example done?

I started with an intention to understand what a monoid ring is, but by now I see nothing beyond notations. Perhaps, you could propose a more simple example for me to get an intuition on how a monoid ring is intended to work?

Answer (score 2):

I decided to keep the question so that other people can look at it later.

So my approach was to go further and transform $$(1 2) + 2\cdot (1 3) + 3\cdot(2 3) + 4\cdot(1 2 3) + 5\cdot(3 2 1)$$
to $$f = f_1 \cdot f_{(1 2)} + f_2 \cdot f_{(1 3)} + f_3 \cdot f_{(2 3)} + f_4 \cdot f_{(1 2 3)} + f_5 \cdot f_{(3 2 1)}$$ using the inclusions. In fact, all we have to do is to map $a \mapsto f_a$ and $\sigma \mapsto f_\sigma$.

Then, we can evaluate $f$ using the definition of the product. For example:
$$f((1 2)) = \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2)}f_1(\tau)f_{(1 2)}(\rho) + \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2)}f_2(\tau)f_{(1 3)}(\rho) + \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2)}f_3(\tau)f_{(2 3)}(\rho) + \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2)}f_4(\tau)f_{(1 2 3)}(\rho) + \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2)}f_5(\tau)f_{(3 2 1)}(\rho).$$

At this point we can look into the group table of $S_3$ and calculate all these products. However, we know that $f_a$ ignores all $\tau \ne id$ and sets them to $0$. For $\tau = id$ the $ f_a(\tau) = a$. Hence we can simplify:
$$f((12)) = f_{(1 2)}((1 2)) + 2 \cdot f_{(1 3)}((1 2)) + 3 \cdot f_{(2 3)}((1 2)) + 4 \cdot f_{(1 2 3)}(1 2) + 5 \cdot f_{(3 2 1)}(1 2).$$
From the second inclusion we know that $f_\tau(\sigma) = 1 \Leftrightarrow \tau = \sigma$, hence we get $$f((1 2)) = 1 \cdot f_{(1 2)}((1 2)) = 1.$$
That is exactly the value of my simple function $f$. Another example with $(1 2 3)$:
$$\begin{array}{rcl}f((1 2 3)) &=& \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2 3)}f_1(\tau)f_{(1 2)}(\rho) + \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2 3)}f_2(\tau)f_{(1 3)}(\rho) + \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2 3)}f_3(\tau)f_{(2 3)}(\rho) \\ &+& \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2 3)}f_4(\tau)f_{(1 2 3)}(\rho) + \sum_{\tau, \rho \in S_3 \atop \text{ with } \tau \rho = (1 2 3)}f_5(\tau)f_{(3 2 1)}(\rho) \\
&=& f_{(1 2)}((1 2 3)) + 2 \cdot f_{(1 3)}((1 2 3)) + 3 \cdot f_{(2 3)}((1 2 3)) + 4 \cdot f_{(1 2 3)}((1 2 3)) + 5 \cdot f_{(3 2 1)}((1 2 3))\\
&=& 4 \cdot f_{(1 2 3)}((1 2 3)) \\
&=& 4.
\end{array}$$
The construction is (notaionally) very complex, but I think that the main idea of decomposing $f$ in monoid rings is clear to me by now.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I think I didn't understand what you were trying to do before.

Comment: No problem :) Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The numbers you're using as coefficients in the group ring are completely unrelated to the numbers you're using to write down permutations; they have nothing to do with each other and don't interact in any computations. An expression like $4 \cdot (123)$ is just an abstract scalar $4 \in R$ multiplied abstractly by an element of the group $(123) \in G$ and it doesn't simplify further.

You are absolutely correct that this is very confusing; you can notate permutations using an abstract set of symbols instead to avoid this, e.g. $(abc)$ instead of $(123)$.

If you want a less confusing example to start with take $G = \mathbb{N}$ (including $0$). Then $R[\mathbb{N}]$ turns out to be isomorphic to the ring of polynomials over $R$ in one variable, with the abstract $i \in \mathbb{N}$ corresponding to the polynomial $x^i$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Indeed, but a switch from $G = \mathbb{Z}$ to $G = \mathbb{N}$ does not change something significantly in the example. My problem was mainly to compute the example up to the end and understand the place where to use the inclusions. And how to use them. I added my own answer upstairs.

Comment: @jupiter: you've misread my suggestion; I said to change the monoid to $\mathbb{N}$, not the coefficients. I suggest not specifying the coefficients at all to make it clearer what's going on. Your example computations in your question are already correct and no further simplification is possible.

Comment: Oh, excuse me. That is true, I misread this. My proposal was that taking a group with 6 elements is going to make the life easier as when taking an infinite group. Or an infinite monoid - in the case of $\mathbb{N}$. It seems like I made a mistake in this proposal :)

Comment: I think it's much more confusing, yes. The group algebra of $S_3$ is not a familiar algebra but the monoid algebra of $\mathbb{N}$ is the polynomial algebra so it's very familiar.

Comment: could you please elaborate the point why $R\mathbb{N} \cong R[x]$?  Setting $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and defining polynomials as sequences of coefficients I get $(0,14,0,2,0, ...)$ for $f=2x^3+14x$ and $(1,2,1,0,...)$ for $g=x^2+2x+1$. The Cauchy product results in $(0,14,28,16,4,2,0,...)$, the multiplication in $R\mathbb{Z}$ in $(0,28,14,4,0,0,2,0,\ldots)$. So, it is somehow not the same. Where is the isomorphism?

Comment: Your multiplication in $R[\mathbb{N}]$ is incorrect; you should be getting the Cauchy product. Try redoing it or posting it here for correction. I do not recommend being specific about what $R$ is, the identification with the polynomial algebra is for all $R$.

Comment: Now I am confused. According to the multiplication formula from the main post, $(f \cdot g)(0) = f(0)g(0) = 1, (f\cdot g)(1) = f(1)g(1) = 16\cdot 4 = 64, (f\cdot g)(2) = f(1)g(2) + f(2)g(1) = 16 \cdot 9 + 44 \cdot 4= 144 + 176 = 320$, etc. So, $f \cdot g$ in $R\mathbb{N}$ turns out to be $(1,64,320, \ldots)$, which is again not the Cauchy product. In the previous' comment calculation I used the same coefficient vectors, but computed the coordinates as e.g. $1 \cdot 3 + 3 \cdot 1$ instead of $0 \cdot 3 + 1 \cdot 2 + 2 \cdot 1 + 3 \cdot 0$ for $3$.

Comment: It is anyway a source of confusion, because I do not see how to calculate the product in $R\mathbb{N}$ correctly. Regarding the isomorphism: I do not see it. Let it be $\varphi: R\mathbb{N} \to R[x]$. What is $\varphi(f)$?

Comment: I am also confused why you wrote $R[\mathbb{N}]$ in the example, because the notation from the definition looks like $R\mathbb{N}$, and $R[\mathbb{N}]$ looks like a polynom ring in $\mathbb{N}$ variables with coefficients in $R$.

Comment: I made a mistake by $f(0)$ in the comment before. Putting it all together, I have $(0,14,0,2,\ldots) + (1,2,1,0,\ldots) = (1,20,53,\ldots)$ and $(0,14,0,2,\ldots) \cdot (1,2,1,0,\ldots) = (0,64,320,\ldots)$ in $\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{N}$ and $(0,14,0,2,\ldots) + (1,2,1,0,\ldots) = (1,16,1,2,0,\ldots)$ with $(0,14,0,2,\ldots) \cdot (1,2,1,0,\ldots) = (0,14,28,16,4,2,0,\ldots)$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. I do not see any isomorphism or verification why $\mathbb{Z}\mathbb{N} = \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Comment: That calculation is still incorrect. You haven't provided details so I can't tell you where the mistake is but those coefficients are way too large. Again, you should just be getting the Cauchy product. To be clear I am talking about $\mathbb{N}$ as a monoid under addition, not multiplication. The isomorphism sends $\sum a_n \cdot n$ to $\sum a_n x^n$.

Comment: What details are necessary? I used $f$ and $g$ from the comments before and multiplication from the 8th line of the main post.